# Find the length of the report to have a Not to Print message

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a SSRS 2008 R2 report, based on the user selection of paraneters, the report is growing horizontally so I need to find the length of the report dynamically to have a message "Not to print"

How to find the length of the report dynamically here I need to check for A3 size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to find out the width directly. But if you know the columns based on the parameters, then you can calculate the width by simply adding the width of the columns.

Use this as a formula in the visibility of a TextBox with your message.

Depending on your parameters the formula might be something like:

```
=IIF(Parameters!FieldList.Value.Count > 8, false, true)
```

Comment: I understand this method of implemetation however, my report has 20 parameters, dynamically passing measures including 3 level of groups so it is not possible for me to count the cell statically, however I really thank you. My full support for your help.

Comment: If you are using a matrix, you could add a second dataset or an element to an existing dataset that returns the number of columns, and follow the same approach.